# Continuous functional on $H^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and $a\in \mathbb{D}$ is fixed. Suppose
$H^2=\{f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n: \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2<\infty\}$ and $\langle f,g\rangle_{H^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\overline{b_n}$. Define
$$\begin{array}{l} \varphi_a:H^2\to \mathbb{C}\\ \varphi_a(f):=f'(a) \quad (f\in H^2)\end{array}$$
(a) Show that $\varphi_a$ is a continuous functional on $H^2$.

(b) Find the function $\psi_a\in H^2$ such that
$$\varphi_a(f)=f'(a)=\langle f,\psi_a\rangle_{H^2}\quad (f\in H^2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) 
\begin{align*}
|\varphi_{a}(f)|&\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_{n}||a|^{n-1}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}|a|^{2(n-1)}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}|a|^{2(n-1)}\right)^{1/2}\|f\|_{H}.
\end{align*}
b) Try $\psi_{a}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\overline{a}^{n-1}z^{n}$.

Comment: Thanks. Why $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}|a|^{2(n-1)}\right)^{1/2}<\infty$ ?

Comment: Try to use root test to just $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}|a|^{2(n-1)}$.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks